# How can I deploy Windows 8 Pro over WDS so that it is already connected to my domain?

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012, wds, unattended, windows-8

I'm attempting to teach myself how to work with Windows Server 2012. I installed the Windows Deployment Service using a Windows 8 (x64) iso file. Installing this on my client machine is actually pretty easy once I setup my BIOS to boot over the network (PXE).

The part I'm stuck at is how to get the client machine to install connected to my domain.

- Are there any blog posts that step-by-step this?
- Any additional roles I need to install on my server (I have WDS, AD DS, DNS)?
- Any additional tools that need to be downloaded/installed on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the WDS documentation on TechNet? It's pretty thorough, including sample unattend files.

Comment: @MDMarra: I'm new to this, so no I did not. I did a Google search on "Windows 8 WDS on domain" but I can't find these TechNet articles you are referring to?

Comment: Googling `"WDS Windows 8 unattended Technet"` returns the [Getting Started Guide for WDS on Windows Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx#WDS_Performinganunattendedinstallation) which is pretty much the start-to-finish resource for getting started with this. Really, everything from Microsoft is well documented. If you haven't read the official Microsoft documentation for a product before you ask a question about it, you need to go read it first.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I deploy Windows 8 Pro over WDS so that it is already connected to my domain?

After you read the documentation that I linked to in the comments, you should have an unattended file linked to your WDS install image. The `<UnattendedJoin>` section of that answer file is where you can input credentials that are used to join the client to the domain as part of the imaging process.

> Are there any blog posts that step-by-step this?

Sure, the WDS docs on TechNet (the official source for Microsoft documentation) covers this *very* thoroughly. And the WAIK documentation covers advanced configurations.

> Any additional roles I need to install on my server (I have WDS, AD DS, DNS)?

If you plan on PXE booting, you need a DHCP server somewhere, but not necessarily on the WDS server. Your WDS server also doesn't have to be a DC. In fact, I'd separate those two roles if at all possible.

> Any additional tools that need to be downloaded/installed on the server?

No, but WAIK and WSIM (part of WAIK) are commonly used on a client machine to customize the unattend file and install images. You can install this on the server if you want, but I never bother.

Comment: I know this question is closed, and MDMarra provides a lot of good information – however, I wanted to let you know that WAIK was replaced by the [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit]( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652) (WADK) for Windows 8.

Also, for future reference, a great location for helpful deployment information is the [Windows 8 page]( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh771457.aspx?) of the Springboard Series on TechNet, which is designed to help IT Professionals to find the resources that they need to prepare and perform OS deployments.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that WAIK had been replaced in Windows 8 (you can tell my W8 experience in the enterprise so far) :) Good to know!